# Subprograma eliminar_repetidos (ADA)

Tags: ada

*Hacer un subprograma que, dada una lista de enteros, obtenga otra lista equivalente que
no contenga elementos repetidos. Lo he hecho en python siguiendo los mismos subprogramas que pondré a continuación y me funciona correctamente. El caso es que al hacerlo en ADA no funciona*

**def_datos.ads**

```
package Def_Datos is
    Max_Elem: constant Integer :=1000;

    type Vector_De_Enteros is array (1..Max_Elemem) of Integer;

    type Lista_De_Enteros is
        record
            Numeros: Vector_De_Enteros;
            Cuantos: Integer;
        end record;
end Def_Datos;
```

**esrcibir_lista.adb**

```
with Ada.Text_Io, Ada.Integer_Text_Io;
use Ada.Text_Io, Ada.Integer_Text_Io;

with def_datos; use def_datos;

procedure escribir_lista (L : in    Lista_De_Enteros ) is
   --Pre:
   --Post:  se han escrito todos los valores de V por pantalla
   --
begin


    for pos in  1 .. L.Cuantos   loop
        Put(L.Numeros(pos), width => 3);
    end loop;
    new_line;

end Escribir_Lista;
```

**esta.adb**

```
with def_datos; use def_datos;

function esta (
      N        : in     Integer;
      L        : in     Lista_De_Enteros   )
  return Boolean is
     -- Precondición:
     -- Postcondición: el resultado es True si N se encuentra en L y False 
        --si no

  chivato:Boolean;
begin
    chivato:=False;
    for i in 1..L.Numeros'last loop
        if N=L.Numeros(i) then
            chivato:=True;
        end if;
    end loop;

    return chivato;


end esta;
```

**insertar.adb**

```
with def_datos; use def_datos;


procedure insertar (num,pos:in Integer;vec:in out Lista_De_Enteros) is
    -- pre: la posicion de insercion sera menor o igual
    --      que el numero de elementos que contenga la lista +1
    -- post: el elemento quedara insertado en la posicion de insercion



begin
    vec.Cuantos:=vec.Cuantos+1;
    vec.Numeros(pos):=num;







end insertar;
```

**eliminar_repetidos.adb**

```
with def_datos; use def_datos;
with esta;
with insertar;


procedure eliminar_repetidos (
      Lista_Original     : in   Lista_De_Enteros;
      Lista_Resultado    : out  Lista_De_Enteros  ) is
   -- Precondición:
   -- Postcondición: Lista_Resultado contiene los elementos de 
   -- Lista_Original pero sin repetidos

   chivato: Boolean;
begin
   Lista_Resultado.Cuantos:=0;

   for pos in 1..Lista_Original.Cuantos loop
       chivato:=esta(Lista_Original.Numeros(pos),Lista_Resultado);
       if chivato=False then
insertar(Lista_Original.Numeros(pos),Lista_Resultado.Cuantos+1,Lista_Resultado);
       end if;

   end loop;





end eliminar_repetidos;
```

**prueba_eliminar_repetidos.adb**

```
with Ada.Text_Io; use Ada.Text_Io;
with def_datos; use def_datos;
with eliminar_repetidos, escribir_lista;

procedure prueba_eliminar_repetidos is 

    V1,  
    V2 : Lista_De_Enteros;  

begin

    put_line("Primera prueba: eliminar_repetidos(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)");
    V1.Numeros := (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, OTHERS => 0);
    V1.Cuantos := 10;
    escribir_lista(V1);
    new_line;
    put_line("Despues de eliminar repetidos:");
    eliminar_repetidos(V1, V2);
    escribir_lista(V2);
    put_line("Pulsa return para continuar");
    skip_line;

end prueba_eliminar_repetidos;
```

*Primera prueba: eliminar_repetidos(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)*

*1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10*

*Despues de eliminar repetidos:*

*4  5  6  7  8*

> Entonces no se que he hecho mal, si me pudieran ayudar a encontrar el fallo... porque en python si que funciona en este caso y muchos mas, gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que el problema está en el subprograma `Esta`:

```
with Def_Datos; use Def_Datos;

function Esta  (N : in Integer; L : in Lista_De_Enteros) return Boolean is   
   Chivato : Boolean := False;
begin   

   for I in 1 .. L.Cuantos loop   -- 1 .. L.Numeros'Last
      if N = L.Numeros (I) then
         Chivato := True;
      end if;
   end loop;

   return Chivato;

end Esta;
```

Comment: jajajaja, como no lo vi antes.... Muchisimas gracias!!!